# How does the jupyter notebook parse unicode variable names and why do I get a bug?

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook

One thing that I quite like working in Python inside jupyter notebook is that I can use some unicode symbols to name my variables. For example, to use greek letters, I type `\alpha` followed by tab and I get `α`.

I just ran into an unexpected behaviour when using a bold capital T, `\bfT` followed by tab which results in .

The experiment is the following. Inside a cell (running Python 3) type:

```
T = 1
 = 2
print(T)  # prints 2
```

To my surprise, the second line is reassigning the variable `T` but I would expect it to be different from . Can somebody please explain what's the catch with using Unicode?

I don't know if it helps, but as another experiment, I can see that the same two symbols as strings are in fact different

```
'T'.encode('utf8'), ''.encode('utf8')  # (b'T', b'\xf0\x9d\x90\x93')
```

How is the notebook processing my variable names?

Comment: I can reproduce this also in the python repl using python 3.7.

Comment: Do you know how to use  as a variable name in the python repl whitout referring to the literal? I'm trying to use `\bfT = 1`, but I'm getting a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is defined in the python language specification for identifiers (variable names). https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

> ### 2.3. Identifiers and keywords
>
> Identifiers (also referred to as names) are described by the following lexical definitions.
>
> The syntax of identifiers in Python is based on the Unicode standard
>   annex UAX-31, with elaboration and changes as defined below; see also
>   PEP 3131 for further details.
>
> [...]
>
> **All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing;**
>   comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.

We can confirm that T and  are equivalent under NFKC using the standard library [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) module.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC','') == 'T'
True
```

So you should avoid using so similar unicode characters in the same scope as unique variable names.

But there's still a lot of unicode characters that are unique and can be safely used in identifiers:

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKC','λ')
'λ'
```

Comment: You can read more about unicode equivalence and normalization on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Comment: As for the "a lot of unicode characters that are unique" - the characters valid as identifier parts must be letters or digits. Emojis are not valid as part of an identifier name.